# loop through the status object and change the values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an object like as below having some statuses and other key value pairs

```
sectionStatus: {
    airSystemsSectionNotesHTML: ""
    airSystemsSectionStatus: "NOT_STARTED"
    codesAndGuidelinesSectionNotesHTML: ""
    codesAndGuidelinesSectionStatus: "NOT_STARTED"
    executiveSummarySectionNotesHTML: ""
    executiveSummarySectionStatus: "NOT_STARTED"
    exhaustEquipmentSectionNotesHTML: ""
    exhaustEquipmentSectionStatus: "NOT_STARTED"
    ...... // some other status
    ......
}
```

I need to loop through this object and change the status from `NOT_STARTED` to `COMPLETE`, is there any efficient way to do this in react JS?

Could any one please let me know on how to achieve this an efficient way?

many thanks in adavnce

Comment: No, there's nothing special. Just do the loop.

Comment: Nothing particularly efficent, just use `for in` or `Object.keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the enumerable properties of the object, check the one with value "NOT_STARTED" and switch:

```js
const obj = {
  sectionStatus: {
    airSystemsSectionNotesHTML: "",
    airSystemsSectionStatus: "NOT_STARTED",
    codesAndGuidelinesSectionNotesHTML: "",
    codesAndGuidelinesSectionStatus: "NOT_STARTED",
    executiveSummarySectionNotesHTML: "",
    executiveSummarySectionStatus: "NOT_STARTED",
    exhaustEquipmentSectionNotesHTML: "",
    exhaustEquipmentSectionStatus: "NOT_STARTED"
  }
}

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(obj.sectionStatus)
  .map(([k, v]) => ([k, v === "NOT_STARTED" ? "COMPLETED" : v]))
)

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

the more readable (at my eyes)

```js
const obj = 
  { sectionStatus :
    { airSystemsSectionNotesHTML:         ''
    , airSystemsSectionStatus:            'NOT_STARTED'
    , codesAndGuidelinesSectionNotesHTML: ''
    , codesAndGuidelinesSectionStatus:    'NOT_STARTED'
    , executiveSummarySectionNotesHTML:   ''
    , executiveSummarySectionStatus:      'NOT_STARTED'
    , exhaustEquipmentSectionNotesHTML:   ''
    , exhaustEquipmentSectionStatus:      'NOT_STARTED'
    // ......   some other status
    // ...... 
  } }

for (let st in el=obj.sectionStatus)
  {
  if (el[st]==='NOT_STARTED') el[st]='COMPLETE'
  }

console.log ( obj.sectionStatus )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```